# What does "クズな" mean?

Tags: translation

Original sentence: 審判がクズなだけ！
Google translates it as "Referee just scrap!"
So if we analyze the sentence:

```
審判(referee) が(GA particle) クズな(???) だけ(only?)
```

What part of speech is クズな and what does the sentence really mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

クズ(屑) literally means ゴミ, waste, trash, litter, garbage, rubbish... and it's often used like "crap" or "a piece of crap". I think it means something like [役立]{やくた}たず or [無能]{むのう} (worthless, good-for-nothing..?).
審判 The referee
が the case particle as a subject marker
クズ crap, rubbish
な The auxiliary verb だ
だけ！only, It's only~~
So I think it's like... "It's only he's a crap referee!" "It's only because the referee is rubbish!"

Comment: Would you like to comment on the part of speech (品詞)? Dictionaries list it as a 名詞, and yet it is followed by な as if it were 形容動詞.

Comment: OMG you reminded me of this thread http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/9652/how-to-write-aikido-wa-ichiban-budo-desu ...

Comment: Google shows lots of results for both 屑な and クズな.　Is it possible that the word has only recently become popular as a な-adjective?

Comment: @Dono, you must be playing the devil's advocate here, I cannot imagine that you don't know that な here is the attributive version of copula.

Comment: @Billy, yes, that might be recent usage, however, that's not relevant for the question. You can also say nounなだけ with non-な-adjectives, e.g. つまらない男なだけさ, it's just that I'm a foolish guy.

Comment: @dainichi Naruhodo...

Comment: @dainichi If it were "kuzu na no da", then yes. However, try another noun: *inu na dake, which is simply ungrammatical. So, if kuzu is a noun, as dictionaries state, then that does not really explain the na here. Lets try a 形容動詞: kirei na dake -- this is grammatical. So, is kuzu also 形容動詞? If so, why do no dictionaries categorize it as such? I think there is more that needs to be said here.

Comment: @Dono, I don't find 犬なだけ ungrammatical at all. Google has lots of hits for it. And I did already try another noun, 男. See my comment above.

Comment: @dainichi I reviewed a few of the Google hits. With more context, yes, I agree that it can be grammatical. In these cases, "N na dake" would mean "N de aru dake" or "N to iu dake". I was hoping to prompt for a bit more discussion on this grammar which just happens to look the same as attributive 形容動詞. But the original poster seems satisfied, so I will answer it myself: it (kuzu) is just a regular noun.

Comment: More grammatically, I think it should be 「審判がクズだというだけ(のこと)だ」「審判がクズだっていうだけ(のこと)だ」. I think 「審判がクズだってだけだ」may also be acceptable, but I'm not sure if it's perfectly grammatical. On the other hand,「審判がバカなだけ」sounds perfectly grammatical. This is because バカ can be used as a na-adjective, while クズ isn't normally used as a na-adjective. (I suspect that the usage of クズ as a na-adjective might be slang.)

Comment: Likewise, つまらない男なだけさ makes perfect sense to me and is acceptable in daily conversation, but more grammatically it may have to be つまらない男だっていうだけ(のこと)さ. I don't know if you'd get corrected if you wrote this in your essay in 国語の授業 in Japanese schools, but I think you'll surely get corrected if you wrote "空手は最も武道だ。", "父はビールな生活を送っている。" or "僕は彼女とお花畑な関係である。"

Comment: @Dono ・・・という感じのことを、chat room で少し話して、結論が出ないままになっています。もしよかったらコメ下さい。 ココです→ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6620/discussion-between-tsuyoshi-ito-and-enno-shioji

Comment: @dainichi, Ah! 犬なだけ has lots of results just because we have other expressions; "a noun+なだけに" and "a noun+なだけあって"! ^^

Comment: There is also [noun]+なわけ, which seems to be the same construction.